# Convert .rtf file into NSDictionary or NSArray

Tags: swift

I have a file (.rtf) that contains data that looks like:

```
[
 {
  "Symbol": "PIH",
  "Name": "1347 Property Insurance Holdings, Inc.",
  "LastSale": "6.8299",
  "MarketCap": 41717882.9375,
  "ADR TSO": "n/a",
  "IPOyear": "2014",
  "Sector": "Finance",
  "Industry": "Property-Casualty Insurers",
  "Summary Quote": "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/pih",
  "FIELD10": ""
 },
 {
  "Symbol": "FLWS",
  "Name": "1-800 FLOWERS.COM, Inc.",
  "LastSale": "9.27",
  "MarketCap": 606557031.66,
  "ADR TSO": "n/a",
  "IPOyear": "1999",
  "Sector": "Consumer Services",
  "Industry": "Other Specialty Stores",
  "Summary Quote": "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/flws",
  "FIELD10": ""
 },
 {
  "Symbol": "FCCY",
  "Name": "1st Constitution Bancorp (NJ)",
  "LastSale": "12.99",
  "MarketCap": 103169203.98,
  "ADR TSO": "n/a",
  "IPOyear": "n/a",
  "Sector": "Finance",
  "Industry": "Savings Institutions",
  "Summary Quote": "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fccy",
  "FIELD10": ""
 }
]
```

Now, I would like to convert this data into something (NSDictionary, NSArray, etc.) that I can use to easily access the data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "txt") else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            return content
        } catch _ as NSError {
            return nil
        }
```

1. Save the `.rtf` file into a location (say desktop).
2. Read the file from that location

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't quite work to the extent I needed it to. Instead, I converted the .rtf file into a .txt file (TextEdit makes it very easy) and simply serialized it from there. Now it all works!